# Dynamic Rails routes based on database models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

So I'm building a Rails site that needs routes based on two different types

I have a Language model and a Category model

So I need to be able to go to a language route /ruby to see top ruby resources and also go to /books to see top books in all languages

I tried routes like this

```
get '/:language', to: "top_voted#language"
get '/:category', to: "top_voted#category"
```

the problem with that was the logic could not figure out the difference between the two and caused some conflicts on the back end

I also tried this

```
Language.all.each do |language|
  get "#{language.name}", to: "top_voted#language", :language => language.name
end

Category.all.each do |category|
  get "#{category.name}", to: "top_voted#category", :category => category.name
end
```

However the problem is Heroku where we are deploying this does not allow database calls in the routes. Is there an easier way to do this? We need to be able to dynamically generate these routes somehow.

Comment: Rails can't differentiate between `/books` and `/ruby`, it will always pick the first matching route from `routes.rb` which is `get '/:language'` in your case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a nice solution to that problem using routes constraints.

### Using routes constraints

As the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) suggests, you could define routes constraints in a way that they check if a path belongs to a language or a category.

```
# config/routes.rb
# ...
get ':language', to: 'top_voted#language', constraints: lambda { |request| Language.where(name: request[:language]).any? }
get ':category', to: 'top_voted#category', constraints: lambda { |request| Category.where(name: request[:category]).any? }
```

The order defines the priority. In the above example, if a language and a category have the same name, the language wins as its route is defined above the category route.

### Using a Permalink model

If you want to make sure, all paths are uniqe, an easy way would be to define a `Permalink` model and using a validation there.

Generate the database table: `rails generate model Permalink path:string reference_type:string reference_id:integer && rails db:migrate`

And define the validation in the model:

```
class Permalink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reference, polymorphic: true
  validates :path, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

And associate it with the other object types:

```
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permalinks, as: :reference, dependent: :destroy

end
```

This also allows you to define several permalink paths for a record.

```
rails_category.permalinks.create path: 'rails'
rails_category.permalinks.create path: 'ruby-on-rails'
```

With this solution, the routes file has to look like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
# ...
get ':language', to: 'top_voted#language', constraints: lambda { |request| Permalink.where(reference_type: 'Language', path: request[:language]).any? }
get ':category', to: 'top_voted#category', constraints: lambda { |request| Permalink.where(reference_type: 'Category', path: request[:category]).any? }
```

And, as a side note for other users using the *cancan*  gem and `load_and_authorize_resource` in the controller: You have to load the record by permalink before calling `load_and_authorize_resource`:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :find_resource_by_permalink, only: :show
  load_and_authorize_resource

  private

  def find_resource_by_permalink
    @category ||= Permalink.find_by(path: params[:category]).try(:reference)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Two routes get '/:language' and get '/:category' are exactly same for rails.
Rails router can't differentiate between `/books` and `/ruby`.
In both cases rails would just look for a route in `routes.rb` which looks something like `/something`, it will pick the first match and dispatches the route to the specified controller's action.

In your case,

all the requests with `/something` format

would be matched to

`get '/:language', to: "top_voted#language"`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an architecture issue. If the clean urls are important to you, here's how I would set this up:

Create a new model called `Page`, which will belong to a specific resource (either a Category or a Language).

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end
```

The database columns would be `id`, `resource_type`, `resource_id`, `path`, and whatever else you want to hang on there.

Your other models would have the reciprocal relationship:

```
has_many :pages, as: :resource
```

Now you can route using a single path, but still have access to the resources from different classes.

Router:

```
resources :pages, id: /[0-9a-z]/
```

Controller:

```
class PagesController
  def show
    @page = Page.find_by_path(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In the view, set up partials for your resource models, and then render them in `pages/show`:

```
=render @page.resource
```

An example page would be `#<Page path: 'ruby', resource: #<Language name: "Ruby">>`, which would be available at `/pages/ruby`. You could probably route it such that `/ruby` routes to `PagesController`, but then you're severely limiting the number of routes you can use elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm a few months late, you've probably already figured something out, but for the future people, constraints might be what you're looking for. You can either set up a lambda that decides based on the request object, or you can set up a class that implements a `matches?` method for the router to call.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints