# Cannot deploy rails Dynamic router on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am doing a redirection based on a model attributes.
It works fine in local but Heroku send me a debug error when I push then finish deploy.

What is that wrong with my code below ? (from [here](http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4))

```
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949383+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-07-27T11:18:21.076083 #4] DEBUG -- :   Passenger Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "passengers".* FROM "passengers"
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949385+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949384+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-07-27T11:18:21.893911 #4] DEBUG -- :   Passenger Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "passengers".* FROM "passengers"
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949393+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949396+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949395+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-07-27T11:18:21.949532+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:50520
2018-07-27T11:18:21.950026+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-07-27T11:18:22.440272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-07-27T11:21:16.609823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-07-27T11:21:16.610597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-07-27T11:21:17.485929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-07-27T11:21:17.501136+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2018-07-27T11:21:17.517026+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-07-27T11:21:17.517896+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:430:in `close': stream closed (IOError)
2018-07-27T11:21:17.517967+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:433:in `handle_servers'
2018-07-27T11:21:17.517939+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:430:in `ensure in handle_servers'
2018-07-27T11:21:17.517991+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:358:in `block in run'
2018-07-27T11:21:17.608339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

If I try to do a db:migrate it throws

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "passengers" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "passengers".* FROM "passengers"
```

`app/models/dynamic_router.rb` **which contains the faulty loop passenger.all.each do..end which is supposed to work ?**

```
class DynamicRouter
  def self.load
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      # faulty part
      Passenger.all.each do |pg|
        get "/#{pg.shortcut}" => redirect("/users/sign_up?q=#{pg.id}&t=#{pg.token}")
      end
        #end of faulty part
    end
  end

  def self.reload
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

`app/models/passenger.rb`

```
  after_save :reload_routes

  def reload_routes
  DynamicRouter.reload
  end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...    
DynamicRouter.load

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because Heroku do not accept database calls from route.config
Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236619/dynamic-rails-routes-based-on-database-models)

```
get ":shortcut" => redirect("/users/sign_up"), constraints: lambda { |request| Passenger.where(shortcut: request[:shortcut]).any? }
```