# rails route: same url pattern with different parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**Routes:**

```
get 'home/index' => "home#index" 
namespace :lawyers do                                                                                   
   get 'all/:division/:district' => "profiles#index", as: :division_district_all
   get 'all/:speciality/:sub_speciality' => "profiles#index", as: :speciality_subspeciality_all
 end
```

**Home controller #Index view:**

```
<% @districts.each do |district| %>
      <%= link_to district.name, lawyers_division_district_all_path(district.division.name.parameterize,district.slug) %>
<% end %>

<% @sub_specialities.each do |sub_speciality| %>
      <%= link_to sub_speciality.name,lawyers_speciality_subspeciality_all_path(sub_speciality.speciality.name.parameterize,sub_speciality.name.parameterize)%>
 <% end %>
```

**Profile Controller #index:**

```
raise params.inspect
```

**Every time I hit with speciality and sub_speciality but this shows division and district value in params. It conflicts because the pattern is similar. How can I get rid of this ?**

Comment: If there isn't any strong requirement, why not having two different routes?

Comment: I can not do this because of strong requirement. It's needed for SEO.

Comment: Let's do the other way round, can you add an additional parameter at the end?

Comment: like ? can you show me any example ?

Comment: If a route has 3 parameters and the other only 2, you can differentiate

Comment: You could use query params or as Balastrong mentioned append a param to the route

Comment: As it is a client project, I cannot change the url. Is there any other way ? Like using constraint ? or anything else?

Comment: I want something like this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236619/dynamic-rails-routes-based-on-database-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to separate the destination method on the controller and update the routes.

I would recommend this approach:

```rb
namespace :lawyers do                                                                                   
   get 'division/:division/:district' => "profiles#division", as: :division_district_all
   get 'speciality/:speciality/:sub_speciality' => "profiles#speciality", as: :speciality_subspeciality_all
 end
```

**Update**: Based on strong requirements, you could use query params `all/:division/:district?query_by=divison` you would only need one route.

```rb
get 'all/:primary/:secondary' => "profiles#index", as: :lawyers_all
```

And then in the controller, manage the logic with something like

```rb
def index
  case params[:query_by]
  when 'division'
    # Division logic here
  when 'speciality'
    # speciality logic here
  else
    # Error handling here
  end
end
```

**Update 2**: As you mentioned on the comments, URL cannot change. Still you would need only one route

```rb
get 'all/:primary/:secondary' => "profiles#index", as: :lawyers_all
```

And check existence on db based on the params, this will impact the performance of your app by creating a lot of db requests and also will create the potential issue of matching with the incorrect classes.

```rb
def index
  if Division.find_by(name: params[:primary]).present?
    # Division logic here
  elsif Speciality.find_by(name: params[:primary].present?
    # speciality logic here
  else
    # Error handling here
  end
end
```

Comment: I can not do this because of strong requirement. It's needed for SEO.
Any other way ?

Comment: Updated with alternative solution

Comment: In this case, the url will be changed! I cannot change the url. I found a way where we can use constraint and but it is not working.

Comment: I want something like this but I got failed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236619/dynamic-rails-routes-based-on-database-models

Comment: And Your solution will failed when I want to hit another action with same url pattern.
like  
get ':slug' => "profiles#show", as: :show

Comment: Not sure why the constraints solution failed for you but you could do that logic on the controller. Regarding `when I want to hit another action with same url pattern` if the url pattern matches it will always go to the same action, so you are responsible of determining the logic in your controller, added another update with an alternative solution of the rout constraints solution.

Comment: As jorge suggested keep 'all/:category/:subcategory' in routes.

keep the url as same, and a different parameter to check whether it belongs to speciality or division. Your url will remain 'all/some_division/some_disctrict?type=division' and for other one it will be  'all/some_speciality/some_sub_speciality?type=speciality' as query parameters don't affect SEO but url does. 

You should handle these conditions in controller `index` method to provide relevant data on the basis of type and category.